# Column of Names Spread Out to 6 Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IYUzNXheSEb_MMrcmSUzF55p6MN1k7PbJgfyHkE-aI/edit?usp=sharing) with a list of names in Column A. **Is there a formula to distribute these names equally across 6 columns?** I currently have 80 names, and I know this won't divide the names equally between the 6 columns. But, could it be set up to where it will distribute the names equally until the last column, which will have more names in it because it doesn't divide equally?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,tocol(A2:A,1),
     Λ,wrapcols(Σ,quotient(counta(Σ),6),),
     Γ,choosecols(Λ,7),
     {choosecols(Λ,sequence(6));{makearray(counta(Γ),5,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0))),iferror(chooserows(Γ,sequence(counta(Γ))))}})
```

[image]

***Updated answer:***

```
=let(Σ,tocol(A2:A,1),
     cols,6,
     Λ,wrapcols(Σ,round(counta(Σ)/cols),),
     Γ,choosecols(Λ,cols+1),
     {choosecols(Λ,sequence(cols));{makearray(counta(Γ),cols-1,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0))),iferror(chooserows(Γ,sequence(counta(Γ))))}})
```

Comment: Thanks so much. So, if I wanted to increase the number of columns by 1, would I just increase each number formula by 1 to do that? Just curious in case I want to increase or decrease the amount of columns to distribute the data in.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an adjustment to the prior solution. If you wish to change the no. of columns that needs to be allocated, you just have to change the number in this part of the formula here `cols,6`